# Magento getAttributeText() not working in shell script

Tags: magento

I have the following code to loop over all products and echo the sku and manufacturer, but $manu is always blank, even though I do get the sku correctly.

```
private function organize() {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $manu = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        // The following also doesn't work
        //$manu = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $sku." - ".$manu."\n";
    }
}
```

This is running as a command line script extending from Mage_Shell_Abstract

What could be wrong with my code?

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer @Tim 's comment (of course credit for him) as we don't need to do another load of product (it is automatically loaded when we do foreach from our collection)

The manufacturer attribute is not automatically selected as it is not stored in the main table (`catalog_product_entity`).

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
```

Answer (score -1):

When iterating through the collection here, EAV attributes are not loaded. Try this instead:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach ($products->getAllIds() as $productId) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->load($productId);
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $manu = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        echo $sku." - ".$manu."\n";
    }
```

Comment: This will exact a heavy toll on the database.  After selecting the products from the database you are then ignoring that and then doing an even more expensive load to load the entire product and its attributes.  Use the collection, but add the attribute as in the accepted answer.